# Reduce typeof object within a parent object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable student that brings in the json response...

```
const student = this.props.response.student;
```

It returns json that looks like this:

```
student = {
    "student_id":"229570000",
    "student_app":"app_002ffjUH989JJ0",
    "address":"124 Aloha Dr",
    "class":{         // object
           "science":"SCI132",
           "mathematics":"MAT032",
           "english": "PSI033",
     },
     ... more data possibly more objects
}
```

I actually need to filter out the objects. As in, remove this class object and any other objects within this object. So how can I remove objects within this json response? (ES6 jsx) Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce `student`'s object properties using `Object.keys()` and check if property value is object:

```
student = {
    "student_id":"229570000",
    "student_app":"app_002ffjUH989JJ0",
    "address":"124 Aloha Dr",
    "classes":{         // object
           "science":"SCI132",
           "mathematics":"MAT032",
           "english": "PSI033",
     },
}

var result = Object.keys(student).reduce((r, key) => {
    if (typeof student[key] !== 'object') {
        Object.assign(r, {
            [key]: student[key]
        });
    }
    return r;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Every time I think I understand `reduce` you go and do something like this

Comment: Nothing! I'm just bad at understanding it sometimes.  Neat answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `forEach` to check if object and then `delete`

```js
var student = {
  "student_id": "229570000",
  "student_app": "app_002ffjUH989JJ0",
  "address": "124 Aloha Dr",
  "classes": { // object
    "science": "SCI132",
    "mathematics": "MAT032",
    "english": "PSI033",
  },
}

Object.keys(student).forEach((e) => {
  if(typeof student[e] == 'object' && !Array.isArray(student[e])) delete student[e];
});

console.log(student)
```

Comment: this is even shorter `Object.keys(student).forEach(e => typeof student[e] === 'object' && Reflect.delete(student[e]));` :)